# Responsive table scrollbar overlaps fixed header

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I’m having a problem in which I hope some of you know the solution.

I’m making a website responsive en for mobile the header will go to the bottom of the screen. So far no problems.
On some of the pages they use tables, which get a horizontal scrollbar on mobile (bootstrap 4 – responsive tables).
When is scroll down the scrollbar of the tables is overlapping my fixed header.

Is there somehow a solution for this problem? When I check the bootstrap 4 website en check some dashboard themes they made themselves, they have the same problem. (example: https://prium.github.io/falcon/v1.8.0/)

Please let there be a solution for this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code in the question - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Can you please provide code sample ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Add `z-index:1;` on your table card div

```
.card.mb-3 {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: aahh... really... i have been looking it all wrong... wasn't thing from the table, but from the fixed header. of course this works... thnx for the quick reply!!!

Comment: i tried to upvote, but as a new member I can't at this moment. My rep is below 15. Sorry.